# Determining if the following sequence of functions is uniformly convergent

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Hi Guys was attempting this question and was wondering if I was doing the question correctly?

Determine whether or not the sequence of functions is uniformly convergent:-

$$f_n:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f_n(x) = 2^{-n}x^ne^2$$

Checking point wise convergence first

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x) =  \lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x^ne^2$$

Taking the Limit as n $\to \infty$ gives the following

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x) =  \lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x^ne^2$$

$$\implies e^2  \lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x^n$$

substituting $n \to \infty$ gives

$$e^22^{-\infty}x^\infty = 0$$

Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x) = 0 = f(x)$$

$$M_n =  sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|,x\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$M_n =  sup|2^{-n}x^ne^2-0| \leq 2^{-n}2^ne^2    ,x\in \mathbb{R}$$

$$(2)^{-n}(2)^ne^2\to e^2 = 7.389$$

Therefore since $f_n(x) \to0 ,n \to \infty$
$$2^{-n}2^ne^2 \to e^2 = 7.389$$

This function does not converge uniformly.

Can anyone tell me if i have done this correctly as it relates tot the evaluation of the question and the procedure for justifying if the sequences of function is uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence converges pointwise to
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}0,&  0\leqslant x < 2\\
e^2,& x=2,
\end{cases}
$$
so it does not converge uniformly. Remember that if a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly, then the limit function is continuous. This limit function is discontinuous, so the sequence does not converge uniformly.

Comment: why did you differentiate the function i am confused about that.

Comment: To find the maximum/minimum value that the function can take. Recall that a continuous function on a closed, bounded interval takes a minimum and a maximum  value.

Comment: yes by the EVT it would attain a max and a min

Comment: Actually I was wrong, the sequence does not converge uniformly. See my edit.

Comment: Recall that the global minimum/maximum may occur at a point where the derivative is zero or at a boundary point. In this case the global maximum occurs at the boundary point $x=2$.

Comment: so what i had originally is correct? thank you for discussing this with me i do appreciate it @ Math1000

Comment: I think some justification of the inequality $\sup|2^{-n}x^ne^2-0|\leqslant 2^{-n}2^ne^2$ is necessary, so I might not give full marks if I were the grader, but you had the right idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100505/discussion-between-amir-and-math1000).

Comment: $f_n (2) = \mathrm e^2$ as you noticed, so $f(2) = \lim _{n} f_n(2) = \mathrm e^2$, then the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is **not** identically zero.

Comment: @xbh Good point, I will edit that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A fact: given $(f_n\colon [a,b] \to \Bbb R)_1^\infty \subseteq \mathcal C [a,b]$, if $f_n \rightrightarrows f [n \to \infty, x \in [a,b]]$ [i.e., converges to $f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$], then $f$ shall be continuous [Proof omitted, hint: uniform continuity]. Compute the pointwise limit:
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x \in [0, 2), \\ \mathrm e^2, & x = 2, 
\end{cases}
$$
which is discontinuous at $x = 2$, hence the convergence cannot be uniform.

To use the definition, note that $x = 2$ would be problematic, so for $f_n (x)= (x/2)^n \mathrm e^2$, consider
$$
\sup _{x \in [0,2]} \vert f_n - f \vert \geqslant \vert f_n (2 - 2n^{-1}) - f(2-2n^{-1})\vert = (1 - 1/n)^n \mathrm e^2 \xrightarrow {n \to +\infty} \mathrm e^1 \neq 0, 
$$
hence the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Great answer. I think yours should be the accepted answer, in all honesty.

Comment: im a bit confused when i evaluated the point wise limit it showed the function tended to zero and then looking to see if it was uniformly convergent i saw that the function tended to $e^2$ is that wrong based what your showing?

Comment: I don't quite follow… If I get this correctly, did you try to say that you got two different limits? This is not possible.

Comment: im asking based on my solution above is that inaccurate based on evaluating the limit?

Comment: $x = 2$ should be considered in particular. So your attempt above is not correct.

Comment: oh your given ref to that specific situation for when x = 2, in terms me evaluating the point wise convergence is that wrong as well?